# How to create your own template for STL vector?

Tags: c++, stl

How to create your own template for STL vector ?
This is good or i need anything else ???

```
template<class T>
class MainVector {
private:
T *m_ptv;
int m_size,
    m_index;
public:
MainVector() : m_size(0), m_index(0), m_ptv(NULL) { }
MainVector(int);
~MainVector() { delete[] m_ptv; }
void addOneElem(const T &);
T *getVecor();
int getSizeVector();
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const MainVector &vect);
};
```

Comment: Do you mean how to create a drop-in replacement for `std::vector`?

Comment: You forgot something essential: the vector guarantees contiguous storage of any type (even non-default-constructible objects), so you'd need to use placement new instead to construct the elements in place.

Comment: What's the difference between your vector and `std::vector`?

Comment: Compared to the std::vector, your template is very simple. The vector of STL has dozens of member functions for capacity, element access, modifiers and iterators.

Comment: And what on earth does this have to do with [tag:STL]??

Comment: _@Ego Voziyanov_ You'll need loads of _anything else_. Have a look at the implementation of `std::vector` to actually see _what else_.

Comment: OKAY. Thanks. I sold it. Done

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate buffer in memory with some initial buffer size (re-allocate&copy when space is exceeded to ensure memory is contiguous, if needed) instead of calling constructors (`new`) on your types.

Size of buffer is calculated like `sizeof(T) * desiredMaxItems`.

You have to implement an iterator type that will be able to `reinterpet_cast` and offset in this block of memory to `T*` value. And offset is somewhat created by calculation `sizeof(T) * index`.

`erase` method of your vector class may (optionally) zero `sizeof(T)` bytes at item offset in internal buffer, and then shift-down values left *after* erased value (`-1`) and update internal `itemCount` field, to avoid "empty" spaces in internal buffer.

This could be skipped if you will store not the `T` data, but directly an iterator instance with something like `bool exists` field. In last case `exists` is set to false and this item indicates it does not exist. In some cases such buffer could work faster.